# why some of my xml attributes are in red color in android studio and how to resolve it

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDdCb.png)

How can i resolve this red colored text

Comment: Just try File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart will fix your problem.

Comment: Go to File -> Click Sync Project with Gradle